# Is it possible to have JavaScript alert() notification limited to a tab instead of the whole browser?

Tags: javascript, alert

Am currently exploring the possibility of having a javascript alert notification limited to a tab in IE.

Comment: Use another browser than IE?

Comment: It's browser controlled. You could just have a custom alert made with JavaScript and CSS that will block the current tab (not that it's even possible to block the entire browser).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) instead and show a notification without this ugly alert() message a bit out of fashion.

Using the [modal option](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message) will add an overlay over the page acting kind of like the old alert.